# Best way to create objects at runtime?

Tags: c++, oop, object, dynamic-memory-allocation

I have a program in C++ with three classes. The program has a simple learning algorithm that tells it what to do in runtime... In some cases, I need to create multiple objects (for any of the classes) at any given time. The number of objects can be 10, or 100... n objects could be created at runtime.

When creating the object dynamically and when fulfilling what the object needs to do, I need to delete that specific object.

What's the most efficient to do this in C++?

Comment: I don't know its efficient or not but you can use vector. see this http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/

Comment: I'd say, if it works, use a `vector`. If for some reason, `vector` doesn't work, then try to make it work. If that still doesn't work, ask for specific advice on that!

Comment: `std::vector<MyObject>(n) myObjects;`

Comment: @Jonathan Potter Isn't there misplaced argument list? - should be like `std::vector<MyObject> myObjects(n);`

Comment: Using a vector is a good default. In particular, because your question can't be answered since the "most efficient" way depends on how you use the objects. That said, if your program creates a bunch of objects, does some processing and then terminates, just *not* deleting the objects is an alternative, so you could also allocate them using `new`. Still, your description is way too vague to give specific advise.

Comment: @LogicStuff: That will teach me to SO on my phone :)